# Performance issue with RavenDB

Tags: database, lucene, ravendb

I've created a simple RavenDB based application where I have 3000 documents consisting of 15 string and int properties. One of the properties (CType) has the same value for all documents and I'm using this field as a way to load all the documents into an array using a Lucene query:

```
var store = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://localhost:8080", DefaultDatabase = "GIS" };
store.Initialize();

using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    var school = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<School>()
        .Where("CType:School") // all documents have CType = "School"
        .Take(5000)
        .ToArray();
```

This code works in that it does read all 3000 documents into the array however it takes 5 seconds or more to complete the load.

Is there some way to do this faster?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are performing a query that has to get 5000 items, send them across the network and deserialize them from Json into a School POCO. 1000 items per/sec isn't so bad, for all this.

Having said that, what are going to do with the list of School items you get back? Generally you don't need to use 5000 items in 1 go, that's why RavenDB has [paging built-in](http://ravendb.net/faq/total-results-in-paged-data-set)

Comment: The reason for loading all the documents into an array is because I need to search across all the string properties of each document for certain patterns. Initially I experimented with a Lucene query to do the pattern search but didn't have any success getting this to work. The best analogy would be doing something similar to a SQL 'LIKE' syntax.

Comment: It's really inefficient to do it this way when you can do this sort of query in Lucene directly. Can you post a question on the RavenDB mailing list http://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/, showing the problem you were having with the query?

Comment: Thanks, I'll put together a description of my query problem and post it to the RavenDB mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually using a dynamic index to do that, so it is probable that the first time that you get it using a dynamic index.
And you should really consider doing any filtering in the server, not on the client.